# Kendo Listview datasource issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-listview

I am working on kendo ui listvie with paging. In this everytime I move to next page it will call datasource. In my scenario if I select 4th page it is calling datasource 4times times.

below is the code

```
function InitiateContactList() {
  var RouteDataSource = null;
  RouteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    create: {
      contentType: "application/json"
    },
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Partner/GetPartnerContacts")',
        data: { lPartnerId: $("#hdnPartnerId").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "get",
      }
  },
  serverFiltering: true,
  pageSize: 2,
  schema: {
    data: "Data",
    total: "Total"
  }
  });

  $("#copyRoutelistdata").kendoListView({
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: RouteDataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#Contactstemplate").html()),
    //selectable: "single",
    //pageable: true,
    change: function (e) {
      var index = this.select().index();
      dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[index];
      if (dataItem != null && dataItem.RouteId != null) {
      //CopyRoute(dataItem.RouteId);
      //HideWindow('MdCopyRouteSearch');
      }
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
      $("#RoutelistPager").kendoPager({
      autoBind:false,
      dataSource: RouteDataSource
      });
    }
  });
  RouteDataSource.read();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using server side pagination?

Comment: Yes, I am using serverside pagination.

Comment: why do you have the DS inside a function "InitiateContactList"? take it out. if you have a doc ready call it there. put it before the list view init